# Do While loop doesn't repeat loop even if conditions where true

Tags: c++, string, do-while, size-t

```
 size_t pos = 0;
 int n;
 char c;

 string temp("x^3+4*x^)8");

 do
 {
      pos = temp.find('^',pos);

      /*code*/

      pos++;

  }while(pos <= temp.npos +1);
  //if temp.find didn't find '^' it will return npos (2^32)
```

What it is supposed to do is find `^` in `temp` and return it's position to `pos`, do abit of code and increment `pos`, repeat the loop if the condition is true. Condition is true if `pos <= temp.npos+1`, i.e it will break from the loop if `temp.find()` didn't find any `^` in the string.

But when I debug, the debugger goes the the do loop once before exiting, even if the condition is true.

**Edit1**
[image]

What I know is `npos = -1` but on my code, when I debug it, it gives me something else.

Comment: Why do you use temp.npos? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/npos/

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/    
because if `find(...)` didn't find the char it will return `temp.npos`

This is what I understood from the find funtion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

npos + 1 probably overflows (because I believe it should be something like MAX_UINT) and then it is (of course) smaller than anything.

Comment: This is true, but it doesn't explain why the do-while loop is acting that way.

Even if I did this `}while(pos<50);` it will not loop 50 times, it will only execute the code once.

Comment: no you are right, and that is why I had that problem, because I put
`while(pos<=temp.npos` `temp.npos = 2^32 - 1`, adding `1` to it, will make it overflow and be `0`, hence while condition is false.

Answer (score 2):

`npos` is defined as `size_t npos = -1;`

`npos + 1` causes overflow, and instead of 2^64 it will be zero.

I would suggest checking for `pos < temp.length()` instead if you want to go this way.

Fix:
Also, you should check for `pos = temp.npos` immediately after find and call `break` from cycle to prevent processing position when nothing is found.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/npos/

from this reference, yes I understand `npos` is a size_t which is an unsigned integeral, it will have a value of -1 (which as a beginner I find confusing as to how an unsigned integer have a value of -1).

But I took a screenshop of `temp.npos` and it's value is greater than -1.

I put the screenshot in **edit1**

Comment: Assigning -1 to unsingned variable immediately causes "underflow", and the actual value will be 0 - 1 = ULLONG_MAX = 2^64 - 1 , that's why you see positive number in debug.

Comment: Uhm, I've seen your screenshots and should add that `size_t `depends on your system - it can be 4 bytes unsigned integer (32 bit system), or 8 bytes unsigned integer (64 bit system). So, npos would be 2^32-1 on x86 and 2^64-1 on x64 system. But still, `npos + 1` will be 0 in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

`npos` is the biggest unsigned integer. `npos + 1` is zero and `pos >= 0`. The loop will repeat if `temp.find()` returns index `0`.

You can change your loop to

```
do {
    pos = temp.find('^',pos);

    /*code*/

    pos++;
} while(pos != temp.npos);
```

since `pos > temp.npos` is never possible.

Comment: yes I figured that out by now, @user3095695 explained that for me